# DefaultActivityHandler inheritance in Virtual Assistant and Skill Templates

Tags: c#, botframework, microsoft-teams

Is there a reason why the Virtual Assistant template creates the bot like:

```
public class DefaultActivityHandler<T> : TeamsActivityHandler
    where T : Dialog
```

while the Skill template creates the bot like:

```
public class DefaultActivityHandler<T> : ActivityHandler
    where T : Dialog
```

Will the skill work correctly when integrated in Teams?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it should work. Skills are meant/designed to be abstract and context agnostic of the client/parent bot (VA in this case). They don't *have* to be, but the idea is that they generally are. Unless the skill needs to work directly with Teams, then it shouldn't need to use `TeamsActivityHandler`. This is because the VA is the one communicating with the skill, not the channel/client (Teams).

This is of course a very simplified scenario. There are absolutely scenarios out there where you would want a skill to be used directly with Teams (as just a bot in that case, it wouldn't be a skill), or where you ***would*** want the skill to have some sort of context for Teams. But by default it's not setup that way and you have to adjust and design for that.

Answer (score 0):

ActivityHandler is a super class, inherited into TeamsActivityHandler. Check the methods implemented in both the classes. Depends on your requirement you can inherit from anyone of the class.

Comment: Yes, I saw inheritance of TeamsActivityHandler from ActivityHandler. What I don't understand is why, in the same template, one piece (the VA) is created teams-compliant and the other (the Skill) is not. So, if I create and empty VA and an empty Skill, connect them following the tutorial, publish them for Teams... they don't work?